# Migrate customer password from Salesforce to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I'd like to migrate customer date including password from Salesforce to WordPress, but I have no any idea how I should implement it.
If you have a good idea, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There's no way to peek at the passwords, they're encrypted, not visible even to sysasdmins (no such column in User table).

Sysadmin can reset password (send an email with pass reset link) or set password to something they chose (`System.setPassword('user id here', 'new password here');` but that's it.

You could try to inject something into login process (login flow maybe or custom login page in community) and save passwords to a helper field... Evil.

If you really have to - migrate them without passwords and send them pass reset links or something from Wordpress.